# What Does This Valgrind Warning Mean? - warning set address range perms

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

When I was running my program against valgrind, I encountered the following warning.

```
Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x4d59d040, 0x6159d040) (undefined)
Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x194f7030, 0x2d4f7050) (noaccess)
Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x3959d030, 0x6159d050) (noaccess)
```

After some googling I found at [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_29.html) that it is a `Diagnostic message, mostly for benefit of the Valgrind developers, to do with memory permissions`, which doesn't tell me much.

My program does allocate a large amount of memory on heap. (Can reach 2-3 GB of ram after a whole bunch of `realloc`'s)

However, the warning appeared despite none of the allocations failed.

So, I'm wondering what this message really means? I don't have some sort of memory permission? (But allocation succeeded)

Comment: The valgrind manual has improved a lot over the past years. If anyone is interested in the meanings of `undefined` and `noaccess` in valgrind now they may refer to [this section of the online manual](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.machine).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It just means that the permissions changed on a particularly large block of memory.

That can happen because of something like a call to `mprotect` or when a very large memory allocation or deallocation occurs - an `mmap` or `munmap` call for example.

The first one you list is setting about 320Mb of memory to `undefined` which is most likely a new allocation, which will be marked as undefined initially. The others are both setting similar sized blocks to `noaccess` which probably relates to a deallocation of memory.

Comment: I see. Is this something that one should ever be worried about? (I'm guessing not as it's `mostly for benefit of the Valgrind developers`?)

Comment: I've expanded and clarified my answer a bit but basically, no, it isn't generally anything you need to worry about.

Comment: What if it lists five errors ending with: (defined) - (noaccess) - (defined) - (noaccess) - (defined)?

Comment: In addition, Valgrind's throws a warning for allocation / free of size ``0xFFFFFD1`` or greater. The real limit should be ``0x10000000`` yet Valgrind add some extra bytes before and after the size. Example : ``malloc(12)``, with Valgrind enabled will give : ``malloc(20 + 12 + 20)``. Valgrind's acceptable size's value is ``0xFFFFFD0`` for the alloc and the free.